# Query Params in Angular route breaking browser back navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing, query-string

I am using the following code to navigate to a Route,

```
this.router.navigate([aUrl], { queryParams: queryParams });
```

After navigating to the route, not able to navigate back on click of Browser back button because of the queryParams (which is very long string about 10K letters),

Does anyone faced the similar problem and how to resolve this issue ?